# Trying install ubuntu 20 desktop on a docker (works perfect with 18.04 and 19.04)

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, vnc, docker

I want to try and install ubuntu 20 as a docker machine. 
Bellow, you can see my setup Dockerfile.
When I connect with VNC to the machine, I see that the display is not working correctly (works perfect with 18.04 and 19.04) this is what I'm getting:

[image]

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop && \
    apt-get install -y gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal && \
    apt-get install -y tightvncserver && \
    mkdir /root/.vnc

COPY ./xstartup /root/.vnc/xstartup
COPY ./passwd /root/.vnc/passwd

RUN chmod 600 /root/.vnc/passwd

CMD /usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 && tail -f /root/.vnc/*:1.log

EXPOSE 5901
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks